# Can I Jump to bookmark using a pattern?

Tags: completion, bookmarks

Using Spacemacs, if I `SPC f r` to search for recent files I am prompted for a pattern. I can enter e.g. a value of `our` which will match a file named `Journal.org`.

However if I do `C-x r b` to jump to a bookmark, and then enter some text to match, the match appears to only work at the beginning of the bookmark name. In other words, entering git will not match in the bookmark jump list a bookmark of `KB/Git`. However, if I have jumped to `KB/Git` previously, searching for git will offer `KB/Git` in the jump history.

Is there a way of suggesting bookmark names where the entered pattern matches any part of the bookmark name, like it does when searching for recent files?

I am aware I can co `C-x r l` and then search with / but am wondering if I can get the same result using `C-x r b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C-x r b` is bound by default to `bookmark-jump`, which uses standard function `completing-read` to read a bookmark name.

So this is not something special about bookmark names or their completion. It's a question about `completing-read` in general.

You can customize option `completion-styles` to control what kind of matching `completing-read` uses. You can use various "fancy" matching styles, such as "flex"/"scatter" and "partial-completion".

Some completion "engines" or alternatives provide even more matching possibilities, but they don't necessarily do that for `completing-read` - they may do it for their own function instead.

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then that's not a problem. You have additional possibilities for how `completing-read` does its matching. And you can also use `icicle-bookmark` for `C-x r b` -- it improves upon the vanilla `bookmark-jump`.

Comment: This probably explains why on two different installs I see different behaviour. One matches what I describe in the initial question, the other performs a match anywhere in the pattern. completion-styles is set to the same on both installs. Is there another setting I should be looking at? completion-category-overrides is also same.

Comment: No idea. The devil is probably in the details. What do you mean by "different installs"? Of Emacs? Different versions? Different platforms/OSes? Be sure to compare using `emacs -Q` in both "installs" (no init file).

Answer (score 0):

ivy/counsel can do this. Just install counsel and put `(counsel-mode t)` somewhere into your configuration. `C-x r b` should get remapped to `counsel-bookmark` which uses ivy for completing bookmark names.

Answer (score 0):

I used `helm-bookmarks` instead of `bookmark-jump` and this allowed searching via a partial bookmark match.